# Non-main print method won't work in Java program

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the "Ratings Report" stuff to print out but all that is printing is the mov1.get stuff. Also, any other problems that are in my program would be helpful to be pointed out as well.

```
public class PopulatePracticec {

    static int countG;
    static int countPG;
    static int countPG13;
    static int countR;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\finalData.in"));
        Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\finalDataCategories.in"));

        do {
            inFile.nextLine();
            String Id = inFile.next();

            String title = inFile.next();

            String releaseYear = inFile.next();

            String runTime = inFile.next();

            String rating = inFile.next();

            inFile2.nextLine();

            String id2 = inFile2.next();

            String genre = inFile2.next();

            Practicec mov1 = new Practicec();

            mov1.setId(Id);
            mov1.setTitle(title);
            mov1.setReleaseYear(releaseYear);
            mov1.setRunTime(runTime);
            mov1.setRating(rating);
            mov1.setGenre(genre);

            System.out.println(mov1.getId());
            System.out.println(mov1.getTitle());
            System.out.println(mov1.getReleaseYear());
            System.out.println(mov1.getRunTime());
            System.out.println(mov1.getRating());
            System.out.println(mov1.getGenre());

        }
        while (inFile.hasNext());
        inFile.close();
        inFile2.close();
    }

    public static void processRating(String rating) {
        switch (rating) {

            case "G":
                countG++;
                break;

            case "PG":
                countPG++;
                break;

            case "PG13":
                countPG13++;
                break;

            case "R":
                countR++;
                break;
        }
    }
    public static int lookG() {
        return countG;
    }
    public static int lookPG() {
        return countPG;
    }
    public static int lookPG13() {
        return countPG13;
    }
    public static int lookR() {
        return countR;
    }
    public static void outputLines(String rating) {
        System.out.println("Ratings Report");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("G = " + countG);
        System.out.println("PG = " + countPG);
        System.out.println("PG13 = " + countPG13);
        System.out.println("R = " + countR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `main` method isn't invoking `outputLines` so why should any of that be printed? Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis *typo* ?

Comment: @UDKOX _typo_ as "they did something they didn't mean to do and that something will not be helpful to anyone else and therefore has little value on this site".

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Does *typo* mean that ? I though it was a flagging option.. That's why I could not find it.. *facepalm*

Comment: @UDKOX In the close vote selection, there's an option that reads: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. **While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.** This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._ That's the one I mean for _typo_.

Comment: Ok so can you correct it so it'll be helpful to me?

Comment: I've already told you what the issue is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't have that one, how many options do you have to close a question ? I only have 5. @MikeManclock Add `outputLines()` in the code to make the call and exeute the function. You haven't called it in the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they are trying to say is that you are not calling the `outputLines` method you created. Within your main method, you need to call your `outputLines` method and pass a string to hold the ratings for the parameter. Once the method is called, it will print the code inside your method. The problem is that you just didn't call the `outputLines` method, so there's no way it will be displayed.

It should look something like this:

```
outputLines(String r); // r holds a copy of the values stored in ratings
```

Also, what you could do is instead of having a method like outputLines, you could create a toString method in which you can pass all the values needed to print the ratings review stuff and return one formatted and concatenated string.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Also, what you could do is instead of having a method like outputLines, you could create a toString method in which you can pass all the values needed to print the ratings review stuff and return one formatted and concatenated string.

Comment: You should probably [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37312780/edit) your answer.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why?

Comment: If you have an answer, you may as well use it include any additional information you want to share, instead of adding it as a comment. You don't have to, just a suggestion.

Comment: Right, i haven't used this much yet, but i will do that. Thanks